# Aligning two buttons to the center using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the div below and will like the two buttons to be aligned to the center.
Right now the buttons are aligned to the left. I added the "justify-content-center"
but still not centered. I am using bootstrap 5

```
    <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-lg-9 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="mt-5">What is this all about. What is this all about. What is this all abour?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Yes Please</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No Please</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "justify-content-center" with "text-center".